# DB2 large update from another table

Tags: sql, plsql, db2, sql-update, database-performance

I have a table with 600 000+ rows called asset. The customer has added a new column and would like it populated with a value from another table:

```
ASSET                              TEMP
| id | ... | newcol |              | id | condition |
---------------------              ------------------
|0001| ... |   -    |              |0001|     3     |
```

If I try to update it all at once, it times out/claims there is a dead lock:

```
update asset set newcol = (
    select condition from temp where asset.id = temp.id
    ) where newcol is null;
```

The way I got around it was by only doing a 100 rows at a time:

```
update (select id, newcol from asset where newcol is null
    fetch first 100 rows only) a1
set a1.newcol = (select condition from temp a2 where a1.id = a2.id);
```

At the moment I am making good use of the copy/paste utility, but I'd like to know of a more elegant way to do it (as well as a faster way).

I have tried putting it in a PL/SQL loop but I can't seem to get it to work with DB2 as a standalone script.

Comment: Is this something where you could gain an exclusive lock on the table perform the updates than release the lock to avoid the deadlocks? http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000972.htm  or is it a too active of a system where this lock would be allowed?

Comment: Unfortunately this is practice for a live system, so the incremental commits seem to be the best way (even though they'll take a few days, it will occur in the background).

Comment: Is it all wrapped in transaction logic? if you're having tens of thousands reads and writes to the table, 100 is probably best, but if only a few hundred updates at are occurring and they are in and out quickly, you should be able to do 1000 at a time pretty easily. taking days down to a few hours at most.

Comment: I'm using IBM Data Studio, which probably wraps it up in some way. It's set to commit after each statement, I've now set it to use 1000 rows as it's ~20% quicker. Do you know if there's a way to use LOOPs without using a package?

Comment: Flagged as opinion-based. What does "elegant" means in your case? For most, its more elegant to avoid PL/SQL. You already had the right answer!

Comment: Ok, ignoring the word 'elegant', my question is how to do a loop on db2 from data studio. I believe I read something about anonymous routines. I think I ended up doing this in Java, but it was a long time ago. (I don't think we had permission on the database to create routines)